# Denodo column DISTINCT values concatenation

Tags: group-concat, denodo, vql

I'm looking for ways to concatenate two or more row values using the "|" separator. I found and used the `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, but it doesn't work for me using the `"DISTINCT"` clause.

Here is an example of a working and non-working query:

**Working (but with a different separator, a comma (',')) -**

GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ROS.route_of_manufacturing) AS "RouteofSynthesis"

**Not functional -**

GROUP_CONCAT('|', DISTINCT ROS.route_of_manufacturing) AS "RouteofSynthesis"

What is the issue with the second query? Is there another method to do what is required?

Answer (score 1):

It's my understanding you're asking about using the DISTINCT clause with the GROUP_CONCAT function in Denodo. The linked post in the Denodo Community, found [here](https://community.denodo.com/answers/question/details?questionId=906Du00000001D3IAI&title=Column%20values%20concatenation), addresses your question.

The only way to utilize the DISTINCT clause with the GROUP_CONCAT function is by specifying one parameter

```
GROUP_CONCAT( [ DISTINCT | ALL ] <field name:identifier>)
```

Additionally, a subquery can be used to achieve the desired outcome:

```
select c1, GROUP_CONCAT('|', c1) 
from (select distinct c1, c2 from <your_view>)
group by c2;
```

Unfortunately, no other alternatives are available.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way we can enhance the group_concat function to enable distinct.  I have array that i need to perform a distinct group_concat with a custom delimiter. Any thoughts